# How to create thread pool for Reactor Netty HttpSever

Tags: reactor-netty

I have created Reactor Netty HTTPSever which works fine with less traffic , I have an requirement to support 4k tps ,even if I send 2k tps its not serving the requests, its supporting only few hundred's of traffic per second. Below is the code used to create the netty HTTP server

```
DisposableServer server = 
                HttpServer.create()
                          .port(port)
                          .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                          .metrics(true, s -> s)
                          .wiretap(false)
                          .handle((request, response) ->
                              Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay))
                                  .flatMap(l -> {
                                    response.status(httpResponseStatus);
                                    return response.sendString(Mono.just(String.valueOf(totalcount.get()))).then();
                                    }))
                          .bindNow();

server.onDispose().block();
```

I suspect it is not able to handle more traffic because of number of threads, it's not able to spin the required number of threads ( not sure about this , its just a guess) , so wanted to know how do I create thread pool and use it in above server.